# Show that $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is equal to its Taylor Series on $(-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I need to show that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ is equal to its Taylor Series (about $a=0$) on $(-1,1)$.

Thus far, I have found the Taylor Series: $\frac{1}{1-x} \approx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}$, and since $f^{(n+1)}(x) = \frac{(n+1)!}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$, the Lagrange Error Formula gives us that $$ |E_{n}(x)|\leq \vert \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\vert = | \frac{(n+1)!}{(1-z)^{n+2}} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot x^{n+1}| = |\frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-z)^{n+2}}|.$$

Now, usually, $z$ ranges between $x$ and something, but I'm not sure what to have it range between here: Should I do four separate cases? $-1$ to $x$, where $x<0$, $x<0$ to $0$, $0$ to $x>0$ and then $x$ to $1$ where $x>0$? I've never done a Lagrange Error problem for a function I'm trying to show is equal to its Taylor Series on a fixed interval before - thus far, I've only done it for all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Or should I just see whether $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+2}}$ is increasing or decreasing on $(-1,1)$ and see where it is its greatest? But then, what is the range for $z$? Is $z$ just any number between $(-1,1)$?

Like I said, I'm very confused because I've never done a problem quite like this before. I know that eventually, what I want to show is that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|E_{n}(x)| = 0$, but I'm having trouble with the bound.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a geometric series.

Comment: @KennyLau I know that, but I'm not allowed to use that fact yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the exact remainder?

\begin{align}\frac1{1-x}&=\frac{(1-x)+(x-x^2)+(x^2-x^3)+\dots+(x^n-x^{n+1})+x^{n+1}}{1-x}\\&=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n+\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\end{align}

If you insist on Lagrange error bound, then recall that $|z|\in(0,x)$, so

$$\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{|1-z|^{n+1}}\le\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{|1-|x||^{n+1}}=\frac1{\left|1+\frac1{|x|}\right|^{n+1}}$$

For this limit to go to zero, we need $|x|<1$.

Comment: because I have to teach this to a bunch of Calc II kids, and we're supposed to use the Lagrange Error formula to do this.

Comment: As you wish... :P

Comment: just call me Princess Buttercup.

Comment: Princess Buttercup?

Comment: it's a reference to the movie The Princess Bride.

Comment: Ah, okay, haven't watched that. Perhaps I should.

Answer (score 0):

Form the product

$$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k-\sum_{k=0}^n x^{k+1}=1-x^{n+1}.$$

When $|x|<1$, the last term vanishes in the limit and

$$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=1.$$